# sharepoint designer 2013 issue opening site due to usage of host header

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-hosting, sharepoint-designer, hostheaders

I have two different SharePoint sites on my server which are separated using host headers on IIS.

Everything seems to work fine but I cannot open my sites using SharePoint designer 2013 and it doesn't give any sensible error to work on.

I tried to connect on server as well as on my local machine and tried both domain and IP but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: did you enable SPD on the web application level?

Answer (score 1):

you must enable sharepoint designer on the web application settings, in central administration.

then, make sure you are site collection admin and enable spd on site collection settings

if you are trying to connect locally, make sure you can resolve the server address. optionally create a hosts entry